# Does Styled Components have cssnext baked in?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, cssnext

I just realized while setting up a new React project today that Styled Components has autoprefixer backed in — does it also have cssnext baked in, or do I need to install postcss-cssnext?

Comment: It doesn't have `ccsnext` baked in. It used [stylis](https://github.com/thysultan/stylis.js) to autoprefix everything back to ie9, since that's what React supports.

Comment: @Tholle thanks! I installed `postcss-next` — is there a good way to verify that it works if I don't have an older browser?

Comment: I have never used a custom `postcss` configuration with `styled-components` before, so I can't be of much help there, I'm afraid.

Comment: Also wondering this 2 years later